# Docker Desktop Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: n. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

When starting Docker Desktop I get this error:

[image: 1]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

How tried to fix it:

- Removed and installed Docker 5 times...
- Removed Docker folders in %appdata%
- Disabled and enabled Hyper-V, tried to run with and without it.

Comment: You got a broken JSON config file.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered that error after disabling and re-enabling Hyper-V. However, I managed to resolve it by uninstalling Docker desktop and then reinstalling it using the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Hyper-V role was not installed due to incompatibility of processor.
If Docker desktop is installed with Hyper-V, check if Hyper-V roles (from Server Manager) is also installed. If not, try installing Hyper-V manually. If it gives try in another server

Answer (score -2):

The problem occurred after manipulation of the Windows defender registry. Tried to disable it through the registry using the video, put it back the way it was, Docker Desktop started up without any problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What video? how did you fix this wtf